# What does "bum-bums" mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

In a Pitchfork article ([Alvvays: Antisocialites Album Review](https://pitchfork.com/reviews/albums/alvvays-antisocialites/)), I came across this word *bum-bum*, and I can't work out what it means. Here's the sentence in which it appears:

> Better yet, in a similar vein, is “Not My Baby,” an aching and ethereal song that **bum-bums** like the answer to the Ronettes’ “Be My Baby.”

Out of several online dictionaries I tried, only Wiktionary had an entry for *bum-bum*, and it said:

> 1. (Brazil, childish) buttocks

The word used in the Pitchfork quote looks to be a verb though, and if it derives from this noun I wonder what hip-related action it might denote and how that can fit into the sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Bum bum", "dum dum" etc are imitative expressions intended to represent a musical beat.

From the book *Blacktime Song by Rosalie Wolfe*, which I found on [Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9IuH4RBPj7gC&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=bum%20dee%20dum&source=bl&ots=HhKAGCTQZo&sig=rajtNBFeJjK-KllK4m5T6ghM-ZU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiX2_j6ioDXAhVMbVAKHTgPBDU4ChDoAQhDMAY#v=onepage&q=bum%20dee%20dum&f=false):

> At the strum of his guitar, she opened her eyes and stared blankly into the darkness.  The notes were soft...
>    With her toes she kept time to outdoor rhythms...
>
> *I ain't nothing but a pun, hun*
>
> *dee dee dum, bum bum*
>
> *I ain't nothing but a gun, hun*
>
> ...*dee dum dum, bum bum*

James K. rightly points out that in your example, "bum-bum" has been adapted as a verb:

> Better yet, in a similar vein, is “Not My Baby,” an aching and ethereal song that **bum-bums** like the answer to the Ronettes’ “Be My Baby.”

Comment: Good, so here "bum-bum" is being used as a verb.